# Responsive Image similar to media temple home page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Help,

I noticed a cool way media temple .net handles their responsive homepage with a container centered content but there is two section when you scroll down that the image goes full width past the container. I can't replicate it on a site im working on.

This is a jfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/uQY6R/

HTML

```
    <!-- start features -->
<div class="features-wrapper">
    <div class="features-container">

            <!-- Lazy Features Plan Row -->
            <div class="row-fluid">

                <div class="span6">

                    <div class="features">
                    <h3>INCLUDED FEATURES</h3>
                        <p>
                            <strong>Yearly Email Reminders</strong><br>

                        </p>

                     </div>

                </div> 

                <div class="span6">

                    <div class="lazypic">
                        <img src="http://messtudios.com/memorial/images/bg-middle-image.jpg" alt="" />
                    </div>

                </div>      

            </div><!-- end Lazy Features Plan Row -->
    </div>
</div><!-- end features -->
```

css

```
    .features-wrapper {
    position:relative;
    background-color:#202121;
}
.features-container {
    width:100%;
    max-width:1150px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    padding:0px 0px;
}
.features {
    padding:0px 20px;
}
.features h3{
    padding:60px 0px 30px 0px; 
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:28px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.features p {
    color:#666;
    line-height:22px;
    font-size:16px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    padding-bottom:30px;
}
.features strong{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFF;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}


.lazypic {
}
.lazypic img {
    width: 100%;
    width: auto\9;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 0;
}
```

Do I need a pluggin for this or can you do it with css?

Thanks in advance. ( I am using bootstrap )
-O

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is... this seems to be working exactly how you want. Do you just mean like this: http://jsfiddle.net/uQY6R/1/, to the edge of the browser window?

Comment: No, here i added an update. http://jsfiddle.net/uQY6R/2/. a smaller container in this one so you can see if you enlarge the browser the image stops.. i want the image to continue extending the full width of the browser like on media temple.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the `max-width: 800px` off `.features-container` or it won't get any bigger than 800px, which will force all child elements to be a max of 800px as well. If you need the text to stay where it is, you'll have to add styles (padding, width, etc.) to that specific div.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uQY6R/4/)**

Comment: Yes is the idea, but I wanted to have a container around the text also... so when you enlarge the left span stays aligned with the rest of the site. Similar to on media temple.. that was the problem I had.